# How to show mat-error once the textbox is dirty and is on focus?

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular-material2

I want to show the mat-error just after the user has started writing something on an input element. Following is my code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" required [(ngModel)]='model.password' #password='ngModel' name='Password' [minlength]='requiredLength' [pattern]="passwordPattern">
    <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.pattern">
        Password must be 8 characters long, one numeric, one special character....
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to show the error-message once the user has started typing in the input. Currently the error shows up on text-box lost-focus. I have also tried in following way:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="password.dirty">
    <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.pattern">
        Password must be 8 characters long, one numeric, one special character....
    </mat-error>
</mat-error>
```

But this also produces the same behavior as before. 
One possible way around would probably using mat-hint. But I don't want to show it as hint as per requirement, I need to show this as error.

By the way, I am using ng-form.

Is it possible to get the specified behavior by using mat-error on ng-form? or I need to customize the css for mat-hint to look it as like the error message?

Comment: Can you post the code of the component?

Comment: @FabianKüng I have used ng-form and in my component file I have just initialized the model and other variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can do it in this way -

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
  <input matInput 
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        name='Password'
        [ngModel]='model.password'
        (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, password)"
        #password='ngModel'
        [minlength]='requiredLength'
        [pattern]="passwordPattern"
        required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.pattern"">
      Password must be 8 characters long, one numeric, one special character....
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in your component.ts add onChange() method -

```
onChange($event, password){
    this.model.password = $event;
    if(!password.control.touched){
      password.control.markAsTouched();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this does serve the purpose. But I don't understand why I should send the event parameter and bind it from the component.ts file? as it is already bound using ngModel. is there any reason for doing that?

Answer (score 7):

This will apply the new matcher to your entire app:

dirty-error-state.matcher.ts

```js
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';
    
export class DirtyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { DirtyErrorStateMatcher } from 'your-path-here';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
    
@NgModule({
...
  providers: [{
    provide: ErrorStateMatcher,
    useClass: DirtyErrorStateMatcher
  }]
})
```

Update on 1/2/2021 by [Reza Taba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944285/reza-taba):

Added **control.touched** so if the user leaves the filed without value, the **required** error kicks in.

Comment: Clean and super useful!!! You can also provide it to one component alone if you don't want the error state matcher to be application wide.
`@Component({ // ... `  `providers: [{ provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: DirtyErrorStateMatcher }]`

Comment: Combining this answer with @arno-2501 comment makes this the best answer by a long way

Comment: Just to be a bit more precise here: "This will apply the new matcher to your entire app". It doesn't have to be. If you want this on the scope of a component only you can provide this in the component scope instead of the root module

Answer (score 3):

If you want to trigger validation on every keystroke done by the user, you have to use a little workaround. I suggest you use a `FormControl`, which will then allow you to set a validator directly on that control and also listen to the changes emitted by `valueChanges` to mark the `FormControl` as touched to trigger validation (maybe there is a better solution to this?).

See the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-7k36dk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Validation is done via the `Validators.pattern` (minimum of 8 characters, at least one letter, one number and one special character), so there is no need for a required or minimum length validator anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. upvoted it as this is definitely a way around. But actually, this is a small portion of a larger form where I needed to show the expected behavior with a minimal change throughout the whole page. The form is already developed on ng-form, converting it into FormControl would lead to change in every input throughout the page. I was looking for a solution without using FormControl,if there is any!